Calculating the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{i = 1}^{n -1}\bigl(1 - \frac{i}{n}\bigr)$ using compactness.
I want to calculate the limit of the sequence where $a_n = \bigl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\bigr) * \bigl(1 - \frac{2}{n}\bigr) * \dots * \bigl(1 - \frac{n-1}{n}\bigr)$ as $n \to \infty$. I want to use compactness theorem to prove the result.

Compactness Theorem : If any statement is true on any finite sub-set
of sentences $\Gamma$ then the statement is true on the whole set of
sentences $\Gamma$.(Where $\Gamma$ is usually a countable infinite set of
sentences)

Now the limit of the sequence formed by finite number of terms is always 1. For example when only taking the terms $\bigl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\bigr),\bigl(1 - \frac{4}{n}\bigr), \bigl(1 - \frac{n - 5}{n}\bigr)$. That is the limit of the sequence $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\bigr)*\bigl(1 - \frac{4}{n}\bigr)*\bigl(1 - \frac{n-5}{n}\bigr) = 1$$.
Then can I claim that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{i = 1}^{i = n -1 }\bigl(1 - \frac{i}{n} \bigr) = 1$$

If you just consider the last term the limit is zero. You need to consider all the terms for each $n$.

This can be written as $\frac{(n-1)!}{n^n},$ which Stirling's formula gives is an easy limit.

Nah you can't claim that

If couse, this product is less then $1-\frac{n-1}n=\frac 1n,$ so the limit has to be...

And the finite number of terms limit is wrong, as written, since $1-\frac{n-5}{n}=\frac5n\to0.$

Just as @Thomas Andrews's comment.
the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1 }\bigl(1-\frac{k}{n}\bigr)=0,$$
due to
$$0<\prod_{k=1}^{n-1 }\bigl(1-\frac{k}{n}\bigr)\leq1-\frac{n-1}{n}\to0.$$
